# How to get the name of the variable in an array, to be used as part of another statement?

Tags: python, numpy, variables

I was creating a new script in which I generate an array that contains a list of strings(`g='g_o.DisplacementMultiplier_'+str(y+1)`, where`y` varies from 0 to 400).
This later has to be used to set four properties in a third party software, but I see that the syntax I'm using set the properties for the variable `g` and not for `g_o.DisplacementMultiplier_#`).

Attached is the code:

```
import smtplib
import math
import time
import imp
import numpy as np
s_o,g_o=new_server
s_o.new()

# Geometry
Bench = 5 # Crest bench
Angle = 23
Height = 15.3

# Frequencies
fz=[]
Tmin=0.01
Tmax=4
Tstep=0.01
Ts = np.arange(Tmin, (Tmax+Tstep), Tstep)
fz = float(1)/Ts

# Calculate x-lenght of slope
dtot= Height / math.tan(math.pi*Angle/180)

# Calculate xmax
xmax = (2 * dtot)+ Bench

# Displacement
g_o.linedispl (0, 0, xmax, 0)
g_o.set(g_o.Line_1.LineDisplacement.Displacement_x, "Prescribed")
g_o.set(g_o.Line_1.LineDisplacement.Displacement_y, "Fixed")
g_o.set(g_o.Line_1.LineDisplacement.ux_start, 1)

# Generate displc multipliers
for y in range (0, len(fz)):
    g_o.displmultiplier()
    g='g_o.DisplacementMultiplier_'+str(y+1)
    g_o.set(g[y].Amplitude, 10)
    g_o.set(g[y].DataType, "Accelerations")
    g_o.set(g[y].Frequency, fz[y])
```

The error from the code is:

```
  g_o.set(g[y].Amplitude, 10)
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'Amplitude'
```

Comment: Welcom to SO!.Please show a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: `g='g_o.DisplacementMultiplier_'+str(y+1)`. Do you want `g` variable not to be the string, but the object with that name, I guess. Right?

Comment: `g` is a string, not a name. You want to use a dictionary, not a bunch of similar names with numerical suffixes.

Comment: How does the "other part" know the name of the variable(s)?

Answer (score 0):

If i understood your question correctly, your trying to accessing property dynamically.

Remove the following line in bottom for loop

```
g='g_o.DisplacementMultiplier_'+str(y+1)
```

Change following these lines

```
g_o.set(g[y].Amplitude, 10)
g_o.set(g[y].DataType, "Accelerations")
g_o.set(g[y].Frequency, fz[y])
```

to

```
g_o.set(g_o['DisplacementMultiplier_'+str(y+1)].Amplitude, 10)
g_o.set(g_o['DisplacementMultiplier_'+str(y+1)].DataType, "Accelerations")
g_o.set(g_o['DisplacementMultiplier_'+str(y+1)].Frequency, fz[y])
```

Comment: Not really, i just need a loop that calls the string DisplacementMultiplier_1.... DisplacementMultiplier_400. so the command at the end of the loop would be
`code`g_o.set(g_o.DisplacementMultiplier_1.Amplitude, 10)
          g_o.set(g_o.DisplacementMultiplier_1.DataType, "Accelerations")
          g_o.set(g_o.DisplacementMultiplier_1.Frequency, fz[y])
          .....
          .....
         g_o.set(g_o.DisplacementMultiplier_400.Amplitude, 10)
         g_o.set(g_o.DisplacementMultiplier_400.DataType, "Accelerations")
         g_o.set(g_o.DisplacementMultiplier_400.Frequency, fz[y])